# Complex Join 1 result 2 same joins

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table which contains some bookings. A booking has an owner and a receiver. Both are numeric and correspond to their account id's. But now I want to retrieve their Names from another table. I can `JOIN` 1 name, but how can i join the other name?

```
    SELECT 
       firstName AS receiverName,
       carName, 
       ownerId, 
       receiverId, 
FROM   system_bookings 
       INNER JOIN link_car_user 
               ON system_bookings.carLinkId = link_car_user.id 
       INNER JOIN system_cars
               ON llink_car_user.carId = system_cars.id 
       INNER JOIN system_users 
               ON system_bookings.receiverId = system_users.id 

WHERE  ownerId = '1' 
        OR receiverId = '1'
```

As you can see multiple tables are used. This now gives the following result:

```
ReceiverName | carName | ownerId | receiverId

Peter        | Toyota  | 1       |     12   
Walter       | Ford    | 13      |     1
```

But I want to add ownerName. Which is also retrievable through the `system_users` table.

How can I do that in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join again with system_users table on `ownerId` as below:

```
SELECT receiver.firstName AS receiverName,
    owner.firstName AS ownerName,
    carName, 
    ownerId, 
    receiverId
FROM system_bookings 
INNER JOIN link_car_user 
    ON system_bookings.carLinkId = link_car_user.id 
INNER JOIN system_cars
    ON llink_car_user.carId = system_cars.id 
INNER JOIN system_users receiver
    ON system_bookings.receiverId = receiver.id 
INNER JOIN system_users owner
    ON system_bookings.ownerId = owner.id 
WHERE  ownerId = '1' 
    OR receiverId = '1'
```

Comment: aliases of 'owner' and 'receiver' would make it even more obvious

Comment: Agreed. Will change it.